# Get next field/column width awk

Tags: bash, function, awk, arguments

I have a dataset of the following structure:

```
1234 4334 8677 3753 3453 4554
4564 4834 3244 3656 2644 0474
...
```

I would like to:
1) search for a specific value, eg 4834
2) return the following field (3244)

I'm quite new to awk, but realize it is a simple operation. I have created a bash-script that asks the user for the input, and attempts to return the following field.
But I can't seem to get around scoping in AWK. How do I parse the input value to awk?

```
#!/bin/bash
read input

cat data.txt | awk '
 for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
  if ($i==input) {       
   print $(i+1)
  }
 }
}'
```

Cheers and thanks in advance!

**UPDATE Sept. 8th 2011**

Thanks for all the replies.

1) It will never happen that the last number of a row is picked - still I appreciate you pointing this out.

2) I have a more general problem with awk. Often I want to "do something" with the result found. In this case I would like to output it to xclip - an application which read from standard input and copies it to the clipboard. Eg:
$ echo Hi | xclip

Unfortunately, echo doesn't exist for awk, so I need to return the value and echo it. How would you go about this?

Comment: Two '{'; three '}'; not a recipe for happiness.  Also, what if the value to look for is 4554?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
read input

cat data.txt | awk '{
 for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
  if ($i=='$input') {       
   print $(i+1)
  }
 }
}'
```

Comment: Haha! That was simple :)
Is it possible to save the result to a variable, and do something with it later on?

I would like to copy the result to the clipboard:
print $(i+1) | xclip -selection clipboard

Answer (score 1):

Don't over think it!

You can create an array in awk with the `split` command:

```
split($0, ary)
```

This will split the line `$0` into an array called `ary`. Now, you can use array syntax to find the particular fields:

```
awk '{
    size = split($0, ary)
    for (i=1; i < size ;i++) {
        print ary[i]
    }
    print "---"
}' data.txt
```

Now, when you find ary[x] as the field, you can print out ary[x+1].

In your example:

```
awk -v input=$input '{
   size = split($0, ary)
   for (i=1; i<= size ;i++) {
       if ($i == ary[i]) {       
           print ary[i+1]
       }
  }
}' data.txt
```

There is a way of doing this without creating an array, but it's simply much easier to work with arrays in situations like this.

By the way, you can eliminate the `cat` command by putting the file name after the `awk` statement and save creating an extraneous process. Everyone knows creating an extraneous process kills a kitten. Please don't kill a kitten.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate explanation! Always nice to learn a more efficient way of coding! :)
Will toy around with this.

Answer (score 0):

You pass shell variable to awk using `-v` option. Its cleaner/nicer than having to put quotes.

```
awk -v input="$input" '
   for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
      if ($i == input ){
         print "Next value: " $(i+1)
      }
   }
' data.txt
```

And lose the useless `cat`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution: delete everything up to (and including) the search field, then the field you want to print out is field #1 ($1):

```
awk '/4834/ {sub(/^.* * 4834 /, ""); print $1}' data.txt
```